# Active admin habtm new button text change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, has-and-belongs-to-many, has-many

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :user_groups
end
```

Similarly, user_group.rb

```
class UserGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

Now the active admin page for user groups is as shown below:

```
ActiveAdmin.register UserGroup, as: 'UserGroup' do
  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.has_many :usergroup_users, as: 'member user' do |user|
        user.input :user_id
      end 
    end 
  end 
end
```

Now this will create the user group form with fields for adding users to the new group. The button for adding new user to the group will be `Add new User Group User`. I want to modify this button label to something else. How can it be implemented?

Part of my problem is solved when using:

```
f.has_many :usergroup_users, heading: 'Add User to Group', as: 'member user' do |user|
...
end
```

This will change the header part to the required text. But the button label is still be a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
f.has_many :usergroup_users, new_record: 'Add member user' do |user|
...
end
```

The `new_record` attribute can be used to customize the button label.

Answer (score 6):

In this way, one can change the text on new and edit pages buttons.

```rb
    form do |f|
      f.inputs do
        f.input :email
        f.input :phone
      end
      f.actions do
        if resource.persisted?
          # edit
          f.action :submit, as: :button, label: 'Update Model'
        else
          # new
          f.action :submit, as: :button, label: 'Create Model'
        end
        f.action :cancel, as: :link, label: 'Cancel'
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still a beginner with rails but have you tried this?

```
user.input :user_id, :input_html => { :value => 'your text' }
```

Comment: Oh... at least I tried :) Again, I'm a beginner but I don't see the code for the button, you can maybe use this : f.button :submit, 'your text'  . Or code the button without a form helper?

Comment: thank you for helping me :) The active admin library DSL is not really similar to the normal rails stuff.